# Install a custom deb package as a bitbake recipe

Tags: yocto, bitbake, deb

```
meta-example
├── conf
│   └── layer.conf
└── recipes-example
    └── debs
        ├── debs.bb
        └── files
            └── example.deb
```

I have a simple layer shown above. What should I write in debs.bb so that I can install the example.deb file during the build and that my final image contains the installed deb package. Further, what other changes do I need to make in my local.conf file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install packages from remote apt repository during build yocto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57115201/install-packages-from-remote-apt-repository-during-build-yocto)

Answer (score -1):

Since you have written the recipe debs.bb which will install the required package as part of building `debs`. You need to add this package in the final target, so you need to add
debs in local.conf. (Make sure bblayers.conf includes your meta-example layer.)

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " debs"
```

Comment: `_append` needs a space `" debs"`